# My VBA code is converting each SELECTED sheet to a PDF but all sheets ends up in all PDF's, not individual ones

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Below is my code, my selected sheets all get saved into different PDF's but they contain all the sheets. I want each sheet to be a separate PDF.

```
Sub ConvertToPDFAndHighlightTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pdfFileName As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim newFolder As String
    Dim previousMonth As String
    Dim selectedSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Get the name of the previous month
    previousMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "mmm" & "-" & "yy")

    ' Create a new folder based on the previous month
    savePath = "My desired location" & previousMonth & "\"

    ' Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    If Dir(savePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir savePath
    End If

    ' Loop through each selected sheet in the active workbook
    For Each selectedSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    
        ' Generate PDF file name based on the sheet name
        pdfFileName = savePath & selectedSheet.Name & ".pdf"
        
        ' Export the sheet as PDF
        selectedSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

        ' Highlight the sheet tab in green
        selectedSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(144, 238, 144) ' Light Green

        ' Add a delay to ensure proper highlighting
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Next selectedSheet

    ' Display a message when the process is complete
    MsgBox "PDF Conversion Complete!" & vbCrLf & "PDFs saved in: " & savePath, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Code is doing everything I want except that the selected sheets are turned into pdf's and those pdf's have all the sheets. I want each sheet to turn into a separate PDF.

Comment: Print each sheet to PDF instead of exporting it.

Comment: IIRC this is unintended behavior with `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`, and can be circumvented by activating each sheet first and then using `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate, how do I activate each sheet ?

Comment: `selectedSheet.Activate`?

Comment: selectedSheet.Activate


        pdfFileName = savePath & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
        
       
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

       
        selectedSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(144, 238, 144) ' Light Green

      
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Next selectedSheet

Still does not work

Comment: Please specify what does or does not happen. My initial guess would be that the `SelectedSheets` collection changes, but I need more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When it is run, I get a run time error 1004. Go to debug and the  following is highlighted, 
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

Comment: What is the specific error message, besides run time error 1004?

Comment: Document not saved, The document may be open or an error may have been encountered when saving.